# postgresSql PIVOT: I want to return dynamic columns

Tags: postgresql, pivot, pivot-table, procedure

I have stored data in DB like this:

| id | week | qty | product_code | related_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2201 | 10 | X000001 | 24 |
| 2 | 2202 | 14 | X000001 | 24 |
| 3 | 2201 | 15 | X000002 | 24 |
| 4 | 2202 | 25 | X000002 | 24 |
| 5 | 2210 | 11 | X000001 | 25 |
| 6 | 2244 | 22 | X000001 | 26 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |

I want to make an sql query with the chosen related_id to get this result:
**For example if i chose the related_id = 24**

| product_code | 2201 | 2202 | 2203 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X000001 | 10 | 14 | ... |  |
| X000002 | 15 | 25 | ... |  |

I want to transform all the week values of the related_id into columns with ASC order and put the right qty in front of every (product_code, week) couple.

Thanks

Comment: Did you already search for the answer? https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bpostgresql%5d%20dynamic%20pivot

Comment: yes I saw them, but I'm new to sql so I couldn't understand some answers and apply them to my problem :(

Comment: The answer is: It's not easily possible because a SQL statement always needs know the the columns beforehand. So there is no easy way for dynamic number of columns. There are some advanced ways to do such (e.g. using stored procedures), but all these are explained properly in the first few results of the stackoverflow search...

Comment: I searched all the solutions on stackoverflow, and I'm sure some answer my problem one way or another but I'm new to sql :/ so I can't find transformed these answers to meet my needs, I tried a lot of things, and the problem is that I don't have much time to train myself on SQL at the moment. I hope that an sql expert will answer my question and take his time and give a very specific answer to my problem before the deadline. otherwise it's not too bad because I managed to do it with code (python) the problem that the execution time takes a long time when there is a lot of data to process.

Comment: Well, this is not a "free write my code" place. We all have something else to do. We can give hints, but we will not write your code. If the hints you can find don't fit your specific problem, please tell us, what you did exactly and at which specific point you got a problem. And once more: You will NOT get an easy solution for your question, because there is none by SQL design.

Comment: well i respect your opinion, i'm not looking for free write my code, i just need help and that's the concept of Stackoverflow, and i think it's not the best place to discuss this type of subjects. ✌️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got finally a solution after a few days of sql training, i post it here, it's may help someone, special thanks for @S-Man for the motivation :)

```
  DO
    $$
    DECLARE
      sql text;
    BEGIN
      WITH latest_create_date AS (
        SELECT product_code, week, MAX(create_date) AS max_create_date
        FROM my_table_name
        WHERE related_id = 437
        GROUP BY product_code, week
      )
      SELECT string_agg(
        DISTINCT 'SUM(CASE WHEN rop.week = ' || CAST(rop.week AS text) ||
                 ' THEN rop.qty ELSE 0 END) AS ' || rop.week || '',
        ', '
      ) INTO sql
      FROM my_table_name rop
      INNER JOIN latest_create_date lcd
      ON rop.product_code = lcd.product_code AND rop.week = lcd.week AND rop.create_date = lcd.max_create_date;
    
      IF sql IS NOT NULL THEN
        sql := 'SELECT product_code, ' || sql ||
               ' FROM my_table_name WHERE related_id = 437 GROUP BY product_code';
    
        EXECUTE sql;
      END IF;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```